# what is rmbgohbj.exe?

Tags: windows-7

I have a laptop that the user is reporting keeps shutting down at random. When checking the logs the above programme always seems to be at fault. It is located in the users appdata folder.

It's not there at the moment so possibly some virus?

I can not find anything on google related to this file what is it?

Comment: That fact that *rmbgohbj* doesn't give any results on Google (except for this page) strongly suggests a randomly generated filename and, threfore, malware. The answers to [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/q/100360) may help.

Answer (score 1):

this looks like a virus. Run a full AV tool scan.